# Drupal 6 custom theme development using Zen starter kit

Tags: theming

I am trying to develop a custom drupal 6 theme with zen starter kit. I installed and configured Zen starter theme kit. My objective is to develop a liquid layout theme from this starter kit. Anybody please tell me how to give layout widths for particular elements and if you have any useful tutorials, please share it.

Answer (score 1):

For setting up a Zen sub-theme check [here](http://mywebclass.org/~nc94/drupal/?q=node/37). And there is a good podcast [there](http://www.lullabot.com/podcasts/podcast-55-john-albin-wilkins-and-zen-theme) ;-)